# Auto-associate page metadata?

Tags: tridion

*Links require SDL Live Content login.*

We can choose default schema (and a mandatory option) in [folder properties](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_04DB0D4B4B1D40CCBC32AFC268CCE241). New components in these folders will have the schema selected with appropriate fields filled out.

We can choose default page template for [structure group (SG) properties](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_B1D62E9FF7BD4EF39DA32CE52274E1BA). New pages in these SG will have the page template selected.

**Do we have a similar option for *page metadata* such that in a given SG, author gets both page template and predetermined page metadata (fields)** for either:

- page creation
- page template selection

We can do this easily with Inline Editing (SiteEdit) and page prototypes. But how would you configure or implement this type of requirement with the Content Manager Explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say there are a number of ways to achieve this:

1) Using the UI 'Page Types' - If the page you are using as the page type this should keep that same metadata.  *I've not tested this!!! maybe you could confirm?

2) GUI extension - When a page template is selected a page metadata is selected based on the page template.

3) Event system.  I'm not sure how well this would work as it would likely have to be on the creation of the page (checking if a default template is used) or on save if a template is used and a metadata schema isn't selected... but then if there is mandatory metadata etc etc.

4) The page template.   This will set the metadata (on publish or preview) - or warn a user that a specific metadata should be set for this given page template.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

John

Comment: I like options 1 and 2. Functionally, as a shortcut I tell authors to take a page they like, make a copy, and update as needed. It's similar to how we deal with Office documents, where what we might call a Word "template" = Tridion page (proto)type. So the CME extension could simply be a button that copies what the inline UI does with page types (copy some page).

Comment: Thank Nuno for an approach for #3 [on TridionDeveloper](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/inheriting-metadata-on-organizational-items).

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question and I can see the benefits of this functionality for Editors. I don't have the answer for you. But AFAIK, even event system might not be relevant here since there are no events fired when you start creating a page unless we save the page. GUI Extension a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new item, this takes place via the GetNewitem() method in the API (or GetNewObject() in old money). I always thought there should have been separate events system hooks for this activity than for that of modifying an existing item. I once suggested this on ideas.sdltridion.com with regard to Components, however someone referred me to the OnSchemaGetInstanceDataPost event hook, and the discussion was over.

So in the case of a new component, the schema is automatically queried, and via the hook, you can interfere with the default data. So far so good, but I still believe that it would be generically useful to be able to modify the default data of *any item type* when first created.